# MySQL password getting munged by powershell in windows

Tags: mysql, powershell, cygwin

I am trying to login to a new mysql server using powershell on my windows workstation. I already have it working in Cygwin but I need to test it in powershell.

```
mysql -h adams.server.com -u schema_owner_adam --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY -p
```

I pasted my password in, that didn't work, then I started typing it in letter by letter multiple times like a dummy, every time it threw back the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'schema_owner_adam'@'1.2.4.8' (using password: YES)
```

After double-checking that I was not in fact a dummy, and going back to cygwin and being able to login fine there, I started getting suspicious of powershell and when I tried sending my password through like this:

```
-u schema_owner_adam:xxxxxx£on12CV
```

it came back with:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'schema_owner_adam:xxxxxxoon12CV'@'1.2.4.8' (using password: YES)
```

Spot the difference!

I assume that powershell is munging the `£` character in my password in the same way when I type it into the password prompt.

How can I sort this one?

I am in the UK, maybe I need to set UTF-8 somehow?

```shell
PS C:\> echo $OutputEncoding


IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : us-ascii
EncodingName      : US-ASCII
HeaderName        : us-ascii
WebName           : us-ascii
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 20127
```

Comment: "*How can I sort this one?*" - Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this..

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I drop to CMD when accessing MySql command line and I get less odd behavior.

ISE will not allow interactive applications to run, so try it in a normal Powershell window first.

If that doesn't work drop from Powershell to CMD by typing:

```
C:>cmd
```

Comment: Makes no difference :(  mySQL still doesn't like it. I tried, I failed. I changed my password and made one without `£`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting an ampersand `&` before the command and then put the comand in double quotes `"`

Also the `£` in the password won't be helping so try putting a tilde/back tick (which is an escape character in powershell) before the £ so the password would look like:

```
xxxxxx`£on12CV
```

In case you weren't aware, if you are using the `-p` option then you must put the password immediately afterwards without a space (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html) whereas if you use the `--password=` option you can have a space.

Unfortunately I haven't got my laptop in front of me and my tablet doesn't have mysql on it so I can't test the command but try this:

```
$server = "adams.server.com"
$user = "schema_owner_adam"
$password = "xxxxxx`£on12CV"

&"mysql.exe" -h $server -u $user --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY -p$password
```

Or if the password is still not working try replacing the last line with this:

```
&"mysql.exe" -h $server -u $user --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY --password=$password
```

Alternativly the code for the other way you wrote is:

```
$server = "adams.server.com"
$user = "schema_owner_adam"
$password = "xxxxxx`£on12CV"
$userandpassword = $user + ":" + $password

&"mysql.exe" -h $server -u $userandpassword --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY
```

Following your comment below, try this line of code that doesn't use any variables:

```
&"mysql.exe" --host="adams.server.com" --user="schema_owner_adam" --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY --password="xxxxxx`£on12CV"
```

Let me know if this works and if not let me know what error it gives you. Then when I'm in front of a laptop later I'll have a proper look at it.

Comment: Thanks Cam but I don't want to leave the password in any command line buffers, so I can't take this approach. I tried just typing the password in with a `\`` but that didn't help.

Comment: Hi Adam, I've changed the answer above to try and accommodate what you want. When you get a chance give it a test and let me know how you get on.